# Not matching function for call to "strcmd" with CCB cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocosbuilder

I got a error, I don't know why?

```
cocos2d::SEL_MenuHandler StartScene::onResolveCCBCCMenuItemSelector(CCObject * pTarget, cocos2d::CCString * pSelectorName)
{
CCB_SELECTORRESOLVER_CCMENUITEM_GLUE(this, "gotoPlay", StartScene::gotoPlay);

return NULL;
}
```

Error at CCB_SELECTOR...: Not matching function for call to "strcmd".

I use the right macro CCB_SELECTOR..., all params are ok.

Can I get any help. Many thanks.

Comment: Changed tag from spritebuilder to cocosbuilder considering that SB has no cocos2d-x support at the moment.

Comment: really ? I search cocosbuilder, all redirect to spritebuilder. Is spritebuilder a upgrade of cocosbuilder ?

Comment: Spritebuilder is a fork of CocosBuilder that works only with cocos2d-iphone v3 at the moment. SB is maintained by Apportable. CocosBuilder is no longer maintained. Maybe its development was picked up by the cocos2d-x devs, I'm not sure. But at this time SB is for cocos2d-iphone, CB is for cocos2d-x and cocos2d-iphone v2.x.